# Determining sigma fields on {0,1}$^4$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $\Omega= \{ 0,1\}^4 $, I am trying to find some $\sigma$-fields, $\mathscr F$ for this sample space. My attempt:

$$
\{ \{\},\Omega, \{(0,0,0,0)\},\{(1,1,1,1)\}\}
$$
This contains $\Omega$ and its complement, the null set and is closed under complements. I'm not sure how to interpret the last condition of $\sigma$-fields for this though. Does this satisfy the conditions required?

$\mathbf{UPDATE:}$

One sigma field can be given by:

$$
\{ \{\},\Omega, \{(0,0,0,0)\},\{\Omega \setminus(1,1,1,1)\}\}
$$

I am trying to find more non-trivial examples of sigma fields on $\Omega$, I've come up with this:

$$
\{ \{\},\Omega, \{(0,0,0,0)\},\{(1,1,1,1)\},\{\Omega \setminus(1,1,1,1)\},\{\Omega \setminus(0,0,0,0)\}, \{(0,0,0,0),(1,1,1,1) \}\}
$$
Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: Maybe it does worth to write down the exact elements of $\Omega$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a sigma field. You seem to think that the complement of $\{(0,0,0,0)\}$ is $\{(1,1,1,1)\}$, but it actually is the set of all $4$-tuples except $(0,0,0,0)$--it has $15$ elements. Therefore your set is not closed under complements.

If you replace the set $\{(1,1,1,1)\}$ with the actual complement of $\{(0,0,0,0)\}$ you would have a sigma field.

(This next statement was written before the question was edited and corrected.)
You have not even written the set correctly, since $(0,0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1,1)$ are not sets. A sigma field is a set of sets. Perhaps you meant

$$\{ \{\},\Omega, \{(0,0,0,0)\}, \{(1,1,1,1)\}\}$$

---

As I wrote in a comment, for any $A\subseteq \Omega$ this is a sigma field;

$$\{\{\}, \Omega, A,A^c\}$$

though for it to be "non-trivial" you want $A$ to be neither $\{\}$ nor $\Omega$. A more complex sigma field, based on two sets $A\subseteq \Omega$ and $B\subseteq \Omega$, is:

$$\{\emptyset,$$
$$A\cap B, A\cap B^c, A^c\cap B, A^c\cap B^c,$$
$$A, B, (A\cap B)\cup(A^c\cap B^c), (A\cap B^c)\cup(A^c\cap B), B^c, A^c,$$
$$A\cup B, A\cup B^c, A^c\cup B, A^c\cup B^c,$$
$$ \Omega\}$$

I got that list by using a Venn diagram for $A$ and $B$ and systematically working through all possible subsets. The first line has zero regions, the second line has one region, and so on. You could get a specific set by choosing, for example, $A=\{(0,0,0,0)\}$, $B=\{(1,1,1,1)\}$. I'll let you find the listing for that particular sigma field. I believe you can call this example "non-trivial."

Note that the example you gave in your last comment is not a sigma field under the usual definition, since it does not include $A\cap B$.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I updated the question. So the complement of  {(0,0,0,0)} is the set { (0,0,0,1), (0,0,1,0),.....,(1,1,1,1) }, this would then be a sigma algebra??

Comment: Yes: I tried to add that to my answer before you wrote your comment but I made a mistake, now corrected. Be aware that you did not include all the conditions on a [sigma field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra). It must also be closed under (countably many) unions and intersections. The set you give in your comment does satisfy those conditions.

Comment: ok, so then if I have the same set as in the question, except that instead of {(0,0,0,0}} I have {(0,0,0,1}}, then another sigma field is the one containing omega, the null set, {(0,0,0,1}} and all the 4-tuples of omega excluding {(0,0,0,1}}? So there are 16 sigma algebras that can be constructed this way

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There are also other sigma algebras, I believe.

Comment: OK so those are trivial. How about something like :
$$
\{ \{ \}, \Omega, \{(0,0,0,0),(1,1,1,1)\} \{  A \}  \}
$$
Where A is the set of 4 tuples excluding $\{(0,0,0,0),(1,1,1,1)\}$ which has 14 elements

Comment: Any set $\{ \{ \}, \Omega, A, A^c\}$, with $A\subseteq\Omega$, would be a sigma field. This may still be considered to be trivial.

Comment: Well I'm trying to find a non-trivial example. If I have A, and B as two distinct 4 tuples, then is the set:
$$
\{ \{\},\Omega, A,B,A^c,B^c, \{ A-tuple,B-tuple\}  \}
$$
no longer trivial?

Comment: So in your sigma field, for example : $A^c \cap B^C$ would correspond to $\{\Omega \setminus \{(0,0,0,0),(1,1,1,1)\}\}$

Comment: @dimebucker91: Yes.